# Problem installing 'systemfit' package in R

Tags: r, installation, systemfit

I am trying to install 'systemfit' package in R version 3.4.2. However, I am getting 'car' error. I have tried installing with 'dependencies' setting but it is still not working.

```
> install.packages("systemfit",dependencies = TRUE)
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/wb480571/OneDrive - WBG/Documents/R/win-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  dependencies ‘car’, ‘sem’ are not available

  There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
          binary source needs_compilation
systemfit 1.1-22 1.1-24             FALSE

installing the source package ‘systemfit’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/systemfit_1.1-24.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1241006 bytes (1.2 MB)
downloaded 1.2 MB

ERROR: dependency 'car' is not available for package 'systemfit'
* removing 'C:/Users/XXX/OneDriveXXX/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/systemfit'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.2/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\XXX\OneDrive \Documents\R\win-library\3.4" C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpGs8XAa/downloaded_packages/systemfit_1.1-24.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘systemfit’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: What happens if you run `install.packages("car")` first?

Comment: It seems "car" is not available for my version 3.4.2. ```> install.packages("car")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/wb480571/OneDrive - WBG/Documents/R/win-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘car’ is not available (for R version 3.4.2)```

Comment: You can try downloading and installing an older version from the CRAN archive.

Comment: Thanks. I updated the version and was able to install "systemfit" followed by "car".